# Angular Bootstrap Modal $uibModalInstance Unknown Provider in Angular 1.5 Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

When I try to close A[ngular Bootstrap Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) inside Angular 1.5 component, it throws [Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$uibModalInstanceProvider%20%3C-%20$uibModalInstance).

It works fine, if I use **Controller** instead of **Component**. Am I missing something?

**[Demo at Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/AIlWI76MrtTGOcbrUHS1)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Angular Modal Demo</h1>
    <my-content></my-content>
</body>
</html>
```

### Script

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module('app')
  .component('myContent', {
      template: 'I am content! <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.open()">Open Modal</button>',
      controller: function ($uibModal) {
          this.open = function () {
              $uibModal.open({
                  template: '<my-modal></my-modal>'
              });
          };
      }
  });

angular.module('app')
  .component('myModal', {
      template: '<div class="modal-body">I am a modal! <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.close()">Close Modal</button></div>',
      controller: function ($uibModalInstance) {
          this.close = function () {
              $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
          };
      }
  });
```

Comment: Possibly related to this [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5808)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem with using `$uibModal` and 1.5 components. To solve problem We need to use `component` property of object attribute used in `open` method.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      component: 'someComponentWithContent', //here name of component
      resolve: {
        user: function () {
          return user; //example resolve
        }
      }
    });
```

Documentation of `$uibModal` says that we have below properties set in component:

> close - A method that can be used to close a modal, passing a result.
>   The result must be passed in this format: {$value: myResult}
>
> dismiss - A method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a
>   result. The result must be passed in this format: {$value:
>   myRejectedResult}
>
> modalInstance - The modal instance. This is the same $uibModalInstance
>   injectable found when using controller.
>
> resolve - An object of the modal resolve values. See UI Router
>   resolves for details.

So instead of using dependency injections We need to use `bindings` in component.

```
var someComponentWithContent={

bindings:{
  modalInstance:"<",
  resolve:"<"
},
controller:someComponentController,
template:"Some template"

};
```

And last thing how to use it in controller of component:

```
function someComponentController(){

  //here example usage of dismiss
  this.modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); //this.modalInstance is $uibModalInstance

  console.log(this.resolve); //here object with resolved params
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/JQlavU0Uxq69WdYxMEmz?p=preview

You need to add `ui.bootstrap` as a dependency here:

```
angular.module('app').component('myModal'...
```

Becomes

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']).component('myModal'...
```

For clarity, and to avoid re-typing, just do this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ /* dependencies here */ ]);
app.controller();
app.config();
//etc.. etc...
```

Comment: I already did when I register module. Could you able to create plunker with the fix you proposed?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I said, I can make it work with Controller. The problem is in **Component** - new in Version 1.5. Could you able to make it with Component?

Answer (score 0):

Maciej Sikora is correct. But also you need to update ui bootstrap to version > 2.1.0, otherwise it wont work.